# Fun and Humor Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What should be done with the [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun) and [humor](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/humor) tags?

I'm not sure if [What should we do with "coolest server names"](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2015/what-should-we-do-with-coolest-server-names) is the exeption, but should we try to clean up questions that aren't directly what a direct issue with a direct answer questions? Then burn those two tags?

Two fast examples I found were [What are the most manageable and interesting server naming schemes being used?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3668/what-are-the-most-manageable-and-interesting-server-naming-schemes-being-used) and [Best system administrator accident](https://serverfault.com/questions/7902/best-system-administrator-accident)

Too soon?

---

**Edit**

Here's some more fun off-topic tags: [subjective](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subjective) [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) [offtopic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/offtopic) [fail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail) [its-friday](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/its-friday) [culture](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/culture) [from-the-trenches](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/from-the-trenches) [work-habits](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/work-habits)

Comment: Never too soon for more cleanup.

Comment: Burn them with fire. And review any post tagged with them to see if it should be strapped to a rocket and fired into the sun too.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that most of those should go. The [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun) and [subjective](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subjective) tags were the first two tags I ever Ignored. That was back in 2009, so that explains why I never see those percolate up to the top.

Comment: [tag:subjective] 3 questions. Buuuurn

Answer (score 2):

Die die die die die die die die die die die.

Over the next few days I'll see what I can do about cleaning up those tags. [subjective](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subjective) is now empty and will die a slow and painful death within a few weeks now that there's no questions in the tag. Now, to do the others!

Comment: I've been flagging questions with these tags. I'm scared to cause front page spam by removing tags. Can you even do that to closed questions?

Comment: @Nix - really old closed questions with poor view counts I just deleted. But no, we have no way of re-tagging without bumping, which is why we do it over a long period of time

Answer (score 2):

[its-friday](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/its-friday) friday, gotta get down on friday...

There...now you can't get it out of your head!

But on a more serious note...maybe there should be a sysadmins site (similar to the programmers site) where some of these questions could end up. Some of them are not bad questions for sysadmins in general but are a horrible fit for where they're at right now. Would there be any interest in something like that? Would there be any use or benefit?

Comment: I have often thought it would be good to have a site where we could have discussions or Q&A on stuff that may not be on topic for SF, yet still have a similar level of discipline. e.g. A place where, amongst other things, we could ask questions about how to deal with bosses, users, auditors, etc. or ask questions that would be far too subjective or localised for SF.

Comment: We tried to get a programmers-like site going it got closed on area51 by non SFers as `likely to pull content away from an existing site`.

Comment: @lain - I'm wondering which site that would be? Are they afraid it would pull off-topic posts away from Server Fault? Heaven forbid!

Comment: I believe it was

Answer (score 0):

I've been on a flagging binge, and was batting 1000 when I hit this question
[What are some "must have" iPhone/iTouch apps for IT people?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2423/what-are-some-must-have-iphone-itouch-apps-for-it-people)

That wasn't accepted, but [What are some "must have" iPhone/iTouch apps for IT people?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2423/what-are-some-must-have-iphone-itouch-apps-for-it-people) was deemed as an acceptable flag.

What's the difference?

Comment: Different people, different opinions on what's which side of the line. FWIW http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1967508#1967508 refers to the one that was declined. You will probably find it easier to just drop the ones that can be voted on into the vote to close chat room anyway.

Comment: The community can vote on Exact Duplicate, Off Topic (Off Topic, migrate to mSF,SO, SU and webmasters), Not a real question, not constructive, too localized). At least that way you get a community consensus. Anything else if flagable too.