# Kill it with heavy crossbow: [humor]

Tags: discussion

Five questions, all closed. This tag is not now nor has it ever been on topic: [humor](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/humor)

May we cast it into eternity never to be revived?

Possible duplicate: [Fun and Humor Tag](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2035/fun-and-humor-tag)

And yet, apparently it was never completely killed.

Comment: It's amazing to see what was not only tolerated but readily accepted on SF in ancient times (a year or two ago).

Comment: I can't wait for the day when @WesleyDavid runs out of amusing implements of tag destruction.  Or all the days until then.  Keep up the good work :)

Comment: @ShaneMadden Kill it with furious kitten clawings. Kill it with catnip. Kill it by burying it in the litter box...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First step: I've merged the [humor](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/humor) tag into the [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun) tag (the latter tag prevailed and some of the questions had both tags.)

Since some of the questions now only have the [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun) tag, we have to decide what to do with them.

---

PS: I liked the Preview message before the merge

> **Merge preview**
>
> humor will be removed from 13 questions
>
> fun will be added to 7 questions

Comment: Actually, [fun] is on my list of tags to bring up for destruction. =|