# Kill it with adamantine gauntlet: [fun]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As Splattne [mentioned in this answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/2510/9770), there is a tag called [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun). Who are we kidding? This is IT.

[fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun) has 18 questions, 17 of which are closed and one of which is locked. Many of the closures may or may not be directly attributable to a certain flag-frenzied feline.

Really, I can't think of any legitimate question nowadays that would be tagged as [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun). It's not a tag that people would watch nor is it one with predictable content. Not to mention, it has nothing to do with Systems Administration (unless simultaneously paired with [cricket-bats](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cricket-bats) and/or [mysterious-reproducible-ground-faults](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mysterious-reproducible-ground-faults)).

[image]

---

### Edit 1

As Iain points out, there are 16 people watching this tag. I saw that when I first perused it, but figured that they were relics of a bygone era. Back in the elder days, when crazy questions like "What is your favorite server naming scheme?" and "What is your worst SysAdmin horror story" were allowed to roam the streets unchecked, the [fun](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fun) was probably a pretty kewl tag to follow. I like to think that that's where the current followers come from and that there's no merit in the follower count anymore.

Comment: Hmm. Having a "fun" tag is contrary to our surly natures.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I have LOTS of fun - of course my users are consequently miserable...

Comment: I've got an old-school Thwack-o-matic I'll get out of the basement for this, when it's time.

Comment: 16 people are watching the tag btw.

Comment: I used to have fun - then I started working for a living.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100% agree - they should die a horrible death.

Comment: horrible, painful, lingering death?

Answer (score 2):

I mainly browse SF while at work. To think that others might be having fun is both offensive and shocking. Kill this tag immediately.

Comment: And by "browse" you mean "talk about the defecation habits of my cat."